# Get the row that have more than one value per column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

```
Chromosome                                             1  10   11    12  13   ...
Syndromes                                                                     
12p13.33 Microdeletion Syndrome;                     NaN NaN  NaN  11.0 NaN   ...
12q14 microdeletion syndrome;                        NaN NaN  NaN   7.0 NaN   ...
15q13.3 microdeletion syndrome;                      4.0 NaN  NaN   NaN 10.0   ...
```

Each row contains only one value, rest of the columns are null values but I think that some of the rows could have more than one value like the last one I have create in the previous example.

How can I check that and get the rows with more than one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for get number of rows with exclude missing values and test for greater like `1` in [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.count(axis=1).gt(1)]
print (df1)
                                  1  10  11  12    13
Chromosome                                           
15q13.3 microdeletion syndrome  4.0 NaN NaN NaN  10.0
```

Or you can test not missing values and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
df1 = df[df.notna().sum(axis=1).gt(1)]
```